# Кодировка текста, возвращаемого mysqli_connect_error()

Tags: mysqli, php, кодировка

Где выставляется кодировка текста, который возвращается функцией `mysqli_connect_error()`?

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) устанавливает кодировку для обмена с сервером: `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")` — может, это и с сообщением об ошибке поможет? Хотя, по идее, оно должно быть либо в ASCII, либо UTF-8.

Comment: Жесть... Сегодня включил комп ничего не менял норм кодировка. Как такое может быть? Может вчера что-то менял и не перезагружал сервер...